# error while building with ionic 2.0.0-beta.30

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic2

I upgraded my ionic CLI version from `2.0.0-beta.25` to `2.0.0-beta.30`.Than I test the simple app using the  following command and it worked fine.

```
ionic start nameofmyapp --v2
```

But when I try to build the app for `android-platform`  I got the following error and apk file is not generated.

```
Running 'build:before' gulp task before build
[23:24:43] Starting 'clean'...
[23:24:43] Finished 'clean' after 112 ms
[23:24:43] Starting 'build'...
[23:24:43] Starting 'sass'...
[23:24:43] Starting 'html'...
[23:24:43] Starting 'fonts'...
[23:24:43] Starting 'scripts'...
[23:24:43] Finished 'scripts' after 106 ms
[23:24:43] Finished 'html' after 149 ms
[23:24:43] Finished 'fonts' after 146 ms
[23:24:45] Finished 'sass' after 2.06 s
[23:24:56] Finished 'build' after 13 s
[23:24:56] Starting 'build:before'...
[23:24:56] Finished 'build:before' after 7.15 μs

 0=65, 1=78, 2=68, 3=82, 4=79, 5=73, 6=68, 7=95, 8=72, 9=79, 10=77, 11=69, 12=61, 13=47, 14=104, 15=111, 16=109, 17=101, 18=47, 19=106, 20=101, 21=115, 22=117, 23=115, 24=47, 25=65, 26=110, 27=100, 28=114, 29=111, 30=105, 31=100, 32=47, 33=97, 34=110, 35=100, 36=114, 37=111, 38=105, 39=100, 40=45, 41=115, 42=100, 43=107, 44=45, 45=108, 46=105, 47=110, 48=117, 49=120, 50=10
 0=74, 1=65, 2=86, 3=65, 4=95, 5=72, 6=79, 7=77, 8=69, 9=61, 10=47, 11=117, 12=115, 13=114, 14=47, 15=108, 16=105, 17=98, 18=47, 19=106, 20=118, 21=109, 22=47, 23=106, 24=100, 25=107, 26=49, 27=46, 28=55, 29=46, 30=48, 31=95, 32=55, 33=57, 34=10

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)


 0=32, 1=70, 2=65, 3=73, 4=76, 5=69, 6=68, 7=10


FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1



* Try:

Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output.

 0=10
 0=66, 1=85, 2=73, 3=76, 4=68, 5=32, 6=70, 7=65, 8=73, 9=76, 10=69, 11=68
 0=10
 0=10
 0=84, 1=111, 2=116, 3=97, 4=108, 5=32, 6=116, 7=105, 8=109, 9=101, 10=58, 11=32, 12=52, 13=46, 14=50, 15=53, 16=49, 17=32, 18=115, 19=101, 20=99, 21=115, 22=10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)


Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/jesus/projects/personal/test-app/ionic-conference-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/jesus/projects/personal/test-app/ionic-conference-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true


Caught exception:
 undefined
```

Any Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,it may be related to the node version so far try a version later than 6.2.1 and confirm that  Node v6 is not officially supported by Ionic. I think it should work fine with a later one

Comment: I just try it with a " Node 6.0.0 " and it work fine  . Thank you